# Having challenges finding a referenced child object / relationship / magic

Tags: salesforce, object-relationships

I inherited the management of a Salesforce org for an NPO that works with Students.

Our Students have Enrollments (in schools).

When an Enrollment is created on a Student, its demarcated via a Checkbox (binary) as the "Most Recent Enrollment" by the creator.

There are multiple Enrollments on any given student.  Information only from the most recent Enrollment, like the City, is rolled up to the Student object.

The way that it is rolled up, are formulas such as "Most_recent_enrollment__r.City__c" .. while there is no "Most_recent_enrollment" object, and fields from it will not show up in any field-viewing pathway that will be shown to you by the "insert field" button, inside the formula creation window.

Would anyone have any insight how this is being done or where to look?

Comment: Is there a direct relation or lookup between your most recent enrollment and the student ? This could be populated by an apex trigger, and allow formula fields to travers that single relation.

BTW: there is a "stackoverflow" specific to salesforce here: [http://salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Yes,

There is a Lookup relationship on Student, pointing to Enrollment, titled "Most_recent_enrollment".

There is also the Master-Detail relationship on Enrollment, pointing to "Student"

There seems to be no special formula inside of the "Most Recent Enrollment" lookup however, that could differentiate which was most recent, so I'm not sure whats happening there.

Thank you Samuel
(ps: how do I move this thread to the appropriate Salesforce section?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your latest comment i would conclude that everytime a child enrollment record is added that is linked to a student record, for that student record the most_recent_enrollment__c lookup field is set to that latest enrollment record. This is likely done by an apex trigger.

Once having that direct lookup relation from the student record to the enrollment record, using this is fairly easy in formula's, and works as you have described above: 
`Most_recent_enrollment__r.City__c`

This formula goes through that lookup relation and displays the city__c field of the enrollment record. You could do the same for any other field in other formula fields.